# Image Issues on iPhone

Tags: css, responsive-design

When I view the website on an iPhone 4s, the right edge of the image is cut off. If I remove the padding it seems to fix the issue on my phone but then there is no padding on my desktop. It seems like there should be some padding on my phone, so I'm not sure if getting rid of the padding is right.

Here is the [website](http://heartcrossings.businesscatalyst.com/).

Comment: Try fixing it using media queries.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue, needed to add width:100% to my images in css